# more sites with cakephp in public_html folder live

Tags: cakephp, routes, web

I have uploaded my company site (cake php) to live server's public_html folder
it is working fine
I want to create another folder named hr and want some static page in it
I have uploaded it, but accessing it as

```
www.mydomain.com/hr/mypage.html
```

it gives error of somethng like invalid controller
how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your folder hr inside as

```
public_html/app/webroot/hr
```

so it will be accessible as

```
www.mydomain.com/hr/mypage.html
```

hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: it worked thank you. but can we put this folder out side app folder and make it accessible via .htaccess or routing?